# Azure Service Fabric Cluster: Machine 10.0.0.X could not be reached for RPC

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Does anyone know which port to open or the firewall rules that are needed for the CreateServiceFabricCluster powershell to be able to deploy nodes on virtual machines?

While creating Azure Service Fabric Cluster on-premise I bumped into issues with Firewall while executing the deployment powershell scripts as domain administrator. I was following https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/

When I have the firewall on in a VM which I want to run as a node the following exception get thrown:

> System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode,
>   String str)    at
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey,
>   String machineName, RegistryView view)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPath(String
>   machineName) System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode,
>   String str)    at
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey,
>   String machineName, RegistryView view)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPath(String
>   machineName) Create Cluster failed. For more information please look
>   at traces in FabricLogRoot. Create Cluster failed with exception:
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.AggregateExcep tion: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Machine 10.0.0.7 could not be reached for RPC.
>   Check netw ork connectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH    at
>   System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.b__30(String machine) 
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()

For now I fixed it by turning off the firewall, but that is not the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to ensure RemoteRegistry service is enabled on your machines.

In case this doesn't resolve the issue, you can try to open ports:
Microsoft RPC EPM: 135
SMB: 445

Sources:
https://serverfault.com/questions/393674/what-is-the-sequence-of-windows-rpc-ports-135-137-139-and-higher-ports-what
http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/ms-smb-protocols.html

Comment: Yes, you pointed me into the right direction: The RemoteRegistry service is will only turn on based on a namedpipe trigger. It seems that service-fabric does not cause the trigger to be executed. So for now I just removed the trigger and updated the Registry to disable idle-stop of the service. Open an elevated cmd prompt and type in: 'sc triggerinfo "remoteregistry" delete' and also edit the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RemoteRegistry \DisableIdleStop to set it to 1 instead of 0.